# The parallel of 6000 years and the six days of creation

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, creation, maseches-sanhedrin, masecheth-avodah-zarah

I have read in the Yalkut Biurim-section of the Mesivta Gemara Sanhedrin (p. 98 of the Yalkut Biurim), that the six days of creation are intertwined with the teaching that the world will exist for 6000 years (Sanhedrin 97a and Avodah Zarah 9a). This explanation seems to be based on the comments of the [Ramban](https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Genesis.2.3.2) (Thanks Rabbi Kaii!).

The Yalkut Biurim brings that the third day corresponds to the generation of Avraham Avinu. Avraham Avinu was like the flowers and the trees that sprouted from the earth, that is to mean that he did bring Torah into the nations and learned them about G-d.

However, the other days are described as follow:

- First day: G-d seperated light and darkness
- Second day: G-d created the firmanent that separated the waters

The Yalkut Biurim says the second day corresponds to the generation of Noach, in which, by means of the flood, good was separated from evil. But, wouldn't it be more logical to say that this happened when G-d separated light from darkness?

Are there any commentaries, meforshim, seforim that explain this list the Yalkut Biurim brings, in which the days of creation corresponds to the generations in which we live and why this specifical order is used, or is this an chiddush on itself?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Ramban is mentioned as the source for the idea in your sefer above, and the Lubavitcher Rebbe goes through it (see "Keeping in Touch Vol 4: Parashat Noach" for example).

Firstly, what's left out from the above explanation that illuminates your question is that each day *corresponds to the revelation of one of the Sefirot*. Here's the quick break down, let me know if it answers your question:

1. **Chesed**. Chesed is the sefira of giving. It is an indiscriminate giving; the desire that everyone should have everything. The light Hashem created was too much and had to be hidden away under the Throne of Glory for the future times. It corresponds to the first 1000 years in that they were years where there was no punishment, people lived for 900+ years, were huge, animals were huge, plants were huge, the weather was great.
2. **Gevura**. This is where punishment and judgement are introduced, starting with the punishment of the flood, and the dispersion (separation) of the people. Good and evil was indeed separated so Avraham could emerge "on the other side".
3. **Tiferet**. Beauty; trees and plants. Harmony and peace - a world that, *despite its barrenness and evil*, received some mercy and peace i.e. Torah. Trees bear fruits, and finally Hashems' creation was bearing fruit; Avraham and his children were doing mitzvot.
4. **Netzach**. The support of chesed, which is reduced chesed; light in the form of sun and moon, more tolerable and stable (and the ability to persevere despite the fact that the Great Light doesn't shine anymore - victory). The great luminaries, the sun and the moon, correspond to the two Batei HaMikdash.
5. **Hod**. The support of severity. Reduced judgement and punishment. The small unkosher creatures. Was a time of exile and middle ages, under lots of little tyrants and dictators - the evil landlords who made our lives hell for 1000 years...
6. **Yesod**. First half of the day saw the "big beasts" get created - the Stalins and the Hitlers. Second half of the day "Adam" was created, which corresponds to the latter half of the 1000 years where there have been a lot of tzaddikim, culminating in Moshiach (the afternoon), the tzaddik and "foundation" of the world!

To answer your question about the separation of good and evil, this does not correspond to the creation of light because the light wasn't taken out of the darkness, it was created from "nothing". It's just the emergence of good. It is pure **chesed**.

For more information, [here's a good shiur](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NijGDqLgIhI) on the topic.

Comment: Thanks! The Rebbe wrote an great explanation. Never heard of the concept that the six days connect to the sefiros. Worth learning more about that. However, my question still stands, are there sources, besides the Ramban, that explain why and how the six days are connected to the 6000 years of the world?

Comment: Sorry, I try to explain what I'm looking for. The Yalkut Biurim says the third day corresponds to Avraham Avinu, but it also says, and quotes the Ramban, that the second day, e.g. Noach, was the one where in which, by means of the flood, good was separated from evil. But isn't it more logical to say this happened with Avraham bringing Torah to the nations?

Comment: @Shmuel my own thought: Noach was separated from everyone else because he was good and they were evil so that's when good was first separated from evil, and it was the "second day". Does that not satisfy? When Avraham started teaching the nations about Hashem, even if we say that it was separating good from evil, it wasn't the first time this happened?